# Sub menu disappears behind main page content

Tags: menu, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have a dropdown css menu that gets gets hidden behind the main page content when viewed in IE7. I've tried changing z-index values but have had no luck. I've also tried suggestions in other topics from this site but none have worked.

The page can be found here: www.boncabe.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the "botmenu" element at the end of the HTML code, and still display it at the top with absolute positioning. This should do the trick!

Comment: Ya, that's an option. I think I'll do it with an conditional tag for IE7 only, because the rest works fine. Thanks.